# Часть речи "А то!"

Tags: морфология

> -Какие удивительные облака  над вершинами гор!
> -А то!

Как вы думаете, чем является "то" в этом варианте? Полагаю, что будь бы это частицей, то писалось бы через дефис. Да и смысловое ударение падает именно на "то".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Это слово-предложение, выраженное междометием. Это междометие, мне кажется, образовалось в результате усечения предложения "А то как  же (иначе)!"

Answer (score 0):

Думаю, что "А то!" - междометие.

Answer (score 0):

Я тоже думаю, что это междометие. Это эмоциональное междометие, выражающее гордость и восхищение.